aws amplify production error for next js "An error occurred in the Server Components render"
this is the function in the "use client" file
const handleOrderTransaction = (index: number) => {
    const transaction = transactions[index]

    if (!form.Name || !form.PhoneNumber) {
        return toast.error("חובה למלא את פרטי המזמין!")
    }
    if (ship && !form.city || !form.customerName || !form.homeNumber || !form.street) {
        return toast.error("חובה למלא פרטי משלוח!")
    }

    if (ship && !form.customerName || !form.shipDate) {
        return toast.error("חובה למלא את פרטי המקבל!")
    }

    if (!ship && !form.storeId) {
        return toast.error("חובה לבחור נקודת איסוף!")
    }

    if (transaction && transaction.type === OrderTransactionPayment.NOT_PAY && !transaction.payDate) {
        return toast.error("חובה להוסיף תאריך לתשלום!")
    }

    let formOrder = {
        ...form,
        storeId: ship ? "" : form.storeId,
        customerBusinessName: form.customerBusiness ? form.customerBusinessName : ""
    }

    if(transactions.every(i => i.paid)) {
        return router.push(`/orders/${form?.id}`)
    }

    if (!transaction) {
        return toast.promise(createOrderZeroAmount(productsSend, formOrder, discounts, totalAmount), {
            loading: "מעביר להזמנה...",
            success: (data) => {
                onGetOrders()
                router.push(`/orders/${data?.id}`)
                return "תשלום בוצע בהצלחה!"
            },
            error: (err) => err.message
        })
    }

    toast.promise(newOrderWithTransaction(productsSend, formOrder, discounts, totalAmount, transaction , ship , form.id), {
        loading: "מחייב תשלום...",
        success: (data) => {
            setTransactions(prev => prev.map((tran, i) => i === index ?
                ({
                    ...tran,
                    paid: transaction.type === OrderTransactionPayment.CHECKOUT ? true : data.paid!,
                    card4Digits: data.card4Digits!,
                    receiptCopy: data.receiptCopy ? data.receiptCopy : "",
                    receiptOriginal: data.receiptOriginal ? data.receiptOriginal : "",
                })
                : tran))
            setForm(prev => ({...prev, id: data.orderId}))
            onGetOrders()
            return "תשלום בוצע בהצלחה!"
        },
        error: (err) => err.message
    })
}

and this in the file fetch-orders.ts with "use-server"
export const newOrderWithTransaction = async (products: OrderProductNew[], customer: OrderCustomer , discounts : OrderProductNew[] , amount : number , transaction : OrderTransactionType , ship : boolean , orderId ?: number) => {
    try {
        const session: Session | null = await getServerSession(authOptions)

        if (!session?.user) {
            throw new Error("אין לך הרשאה לבצע פעולה זו!");
        }

        const client = {
            name: customer.Name,
            email: customer.Email || process.env.DEFAULT_MAIL!,
            address: `${customer.street} ${customer.homeNumber}`,
            city: customer.city,
            phone: customer.PhoneNumber,
        }

        const incomeProduct = products.map(item => ({
            description : item.Name,
            quantity : item.Quantity,
            price : item.Amount,
            currency : "ILS",
            currencyRate : 1,
            itemId : item.productId?.toString(),
            vatType : 1
        })) as IncomeDocumentType[];

        const discountAmount = discounts.reduce((previousValue , currentValue) => previousValue + currentValue.Amount,0)

        let income = [...incomeProduct]

        if(ship) {
            const allShips = await getAllShip()
            const findShip = allShips.find(i => i.city === customer.city)
            if(findShip) {
                income.push({
                    description : "עלות משלוח",
                    quantity : 1,
                    price : parseFloat(findShip.amount),
                    currency : "ILS",
                    currencyRate : 1,
                    vatType : 1
                })
            }
        }

        if(orderId) {
            return newOrderTransaction(orderId , transaction , client , income , amount , discountAmount)
        }

        const couponCode = discounts.find(i => i.type === "coupon")?.Code
        const pointsUsage = discounts.find(i => i.type === "points")?.Amount
        const giftCode = discounts.find((i) => i.type === "giftCart");

        const data = {
            ...customer,
            status : transaction.amount === amount ? OrderStatus.PAID : OrderStatus.PENDING,
            Email: customer.Email.toLowerCase(),
            couponCode : couponCode!!,
            pointsUsage : pointsUsage!!,
            giftCode: giftCode!!?.Code,
            giftUsage : giftCode!!?.Amount,
            homeNumber : customer?.homeNumber?.toString(),
            homeFloor : customer?.homeFloor?.toString(),
            amount
        } as any

        const order = await db.order.create({
            data
        })

        await Promise.all(
            products.map(async (product) => {

                await db.orderProduct.create({
                    data: {
                        productId : product?.productId!,
                        Name : product.Name,
                        Amount : product.Amount,
                        Quantity : product.Quantity,
                        Image : product.Image!,
                        orderId: order.id
                    },
                    include: {
                        product: true
                    }
                })
            })
        )

        return newOrderTransaction(order.id , transaction , client , income , amount , discountAmount)
    } catch (err) {
        throw err
    }
}
export const newOrderTransaction = async (orderId : number , transaction : OrderTransactionType , client : InvoiceCustomer , income : IncomeDocumentType[] , amount : number , discount : number) => {
    try {

        const trans = {
            CardNumber : transaction.cardNumber , CVV : transaction.cvv , ExpDate_MMYY : transaction.expiryDate?.replace("/" , "") , TransactionSum : transaction.amount , NumberOfPayments : transaction.numberOfPayments
        }

        let data = {
            type : transaction.type,
            amount : transaction.amount,
            orderId,
            payDate : transaction.payDate,
            bankAcountNumber : transaction.bankAcountNumber,
            bankBranch : transaction.bankBranch,
            bankName : transaction.bankName,
            referenceId: parseInt(transaction.referenceId!),
            chequeNumNumber: transaction.referenceId,
            accountPayNumber : transaction.accountPayNumber
        } as any

        if(transaction.type === OrderTransactionPayment.CREDIT_CARD) {
            const resp = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL!}/api/create-order-transaction`, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(trans),
            })


            let response = await resp.json()

            if (response.HasError) {
                throw new Error(response.ReturnMessage)
            }

            data = {
                ...data,
                cardName : response.CardName,
                card4Digits : parseInt(response.Card4Digits),
                expiryDate : response.ExpDate_MMYY,
                referenceId : response.ReferenceNumber.toString(),
                token : response.Token,
                numberOfPayments : transaction.numberOfPayments,
                paid : true
            } as any
        }

        const newTransaction = await db.orderTransaction.create({
            data
        })

        if(transaction.type === OrderTransactionPayment.CHECKOUT) {
            return newTransaction
        }

        let receipt : any

        if(transaction.type === OrderTransactionPayment.NOT_PAY || transaction.type === OrderTransactionPayment.DELIVERY_PAY) {
            if(transaction.payDate) {
                await newNotification({ transactionId : newTransaction.id , createdAt : transaction.payDate , type : NotificationType.TRANSACTION})
            }
            receipt = await createInvoice(newTransaction.id , client , income)
        } else  {
            if(transaction.amount === amount ) {
                await createInvoiceReceipt(newTransaction.orderId , client , income , [client.email] , discount)
            }
            receipt = await createReceipt(newTransaction , client)
        }

        return db.orderTransaction.update({
            where : {id : newTransaction.id},
            data : {
                receiptNumber : receipt.receiptNumber,
                receiptOriginal : receipt.receiptOriginal,
                receiptCopy : receipt.receiptCopy,
                paid : transaction.type !== OrderTransactionPayment.NOT_PAY
            }
        })
    } catch (err) {
        throw err
    }
}

why i in the development in local its work fine but after deploy to amplify aws i get this error
An error occurred in the Server Components render. The specific message is omitted in production builds to avoid leaking sensitive details. A digest property is included on this error instance which may provide additional details about the nature of the error
